# Hi, I just started react native and I can't figure out how key extractor works as I am getting the following error

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to know how key extractor works; it's giving me duplicate values and the warning isn't going away when I return item.name ("keys should be unique"): See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O3T3.png).

I tried to add key to my list even though name property values are unique, but why is the key extractor logging out the same values and when I tried to return "item.name"?

Comment: What is key extractor? This isn't a standard ReactJS term.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice keyExtractor is FlatList component prop in react native.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You have to return unique key prop, in keyExtractor method like

```
keyExtractor(item, index) {
  return item && item.id ? item.id : index;
}
```

FlatList would be like

```
<FlatList
  data={arrayData}
  keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
  renderItem={(item) => {}}
/>
```

Comment: Also want to add. If your list has no unique element, just add random value as long as they don't repeat.